# Return two different cell from cellForRowAtIndexPath

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

How can I initiate my cell for returning in the cellForRowAtIndexPath delegate way?

assume there is a var i, i can be 0 or 1;
so:

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
id cell=nil;
switch (i) {
    case 0:{
        static NSString *CellIdentifier=@"RecommendTableCellIdentifier";
        RecommendTableCell *cell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        if (cell==nil) {
            cell=[[RecommendTableCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        }
        dataRow=[dataList objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
        [cell addContent:dataRow];
        [cell.wantToSeeButton setTag:[indexPath row]];
        [cell.wantToSeeButton addTarget:self action:@selector(iWantToSeeClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        }
        break;
    case 1:{
        static NSString *CellIdentifier=@"WantTableCellIdentifier";
        WantTableCell *cell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        if (cell==nil) {
            cell=[[WantTableCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        }
        dataRow=[dataList objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
        [cell addContent:dataRow];
        [cell.wantToSeeButton setTag:[indexPath row]];
        [cell.wantToSeeButton addTarget:self action:@selector(iWantToSeeClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        }
        break;

    default:
        break;
}
return cell;

}
```

both `CustomCellA` and B are defined with a Class and xib.

How can I make this happen?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Assign custom cell to `id cell` before `break;`. ie cell = recommendTableCell in case 0 and cell = wantTableCell in case 1.

Comment: Or return `cell` from each `if` leg.  The problem is you have 3 different versions of `cell` defined there, and you set two of them but return the third.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do this:

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
id cellToReturn=nil;
switch (i) {
    case 0:{
        static NSString *CellIdentifier=@"RecommendTableCellIdentifier";
        RecommendTableCell *cell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        if (cell==nil) {
            cell=[[RecommendTableCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        }
        dataRow=[dataList objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
        [cell addContent:dataRow];
        [cell.wantToSeeButton setTag:[indexPath row]];
        [cell.wantToSeeButton addTarget:self action:@selector(iWantToSeeClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        }
        cellToReturn=cell;
        break;
    case 1:{
        static NSString *CellIdentifier=@"WantTableCellIdentifier";
        WantTableCell *cell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        if (cell==nil) {
            cell=[[WantTableCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        }
        dataRow=[dataList objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
        [cell addContent:dataRow];
        [cell.wantToSeeButton setTag:[indexPath row]];
        [cell.wantToSeeButton addTarget:self action:@selector(iWantToSeeClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        }
        cellToReturn=cell;
        break;

    default:
        break;
}

return cellToReturn;

}
```

Hope this helps... :)

Comment: it did help. is there a better way solve this kind of problem? in two case, most of the codes are the same. can there be another better way?

Comment: Sorry. When you poster it was night in my country. Sorry for being late. I might suggest some better way to do this if you tell be what is the purpose of these two cell and what is the difference between them.

Comment: what can be a good way to achieve that:
i have a view that has several segments, every time i choose on segment, a different tableview with different cells will appear according to what segment i clicked.
can you give me some advice on a better way to solve this?
thanks!

Comment: if the new tableView is appearing at the same view then what you are doing will work.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is you want to avoid code repitition? try this:

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
id cell=nil;

switch (i) {
    case 0:{
        static NSString *CellIdentifier=@"RecommendTableCellIdentifier";
        cell=(RecommendTableCell  *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        }
        break;
    case 1:{
        static NSString *CellIdentifier=@"WantTableCellIdentifier";
        cell = (WantTableCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        }
        break;

    default:
        break;
}
dataRow=[dataList objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
[cell addContent:dataRow];
[cell.wantToSeeButton setTag:[indexPath row]];
[cell.wantToSeeButton addTarget:self action:@selector(iWantToSeeClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

return cell;
}
```

Comment: yes. Property 'wantToSeeButton' not found on object of type '__strong id'
wantToSeeButton is an IBOutlet declared in both RecommendTableCell and WantTableCell.